# How to debug and fix AWS Lambda "InvalidParameterValueException: Layer conversion failed: Could not scan one or more directories" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform

After having added new dependencies to my Poetry project, I get the following error, when trying to deploy my Lambda function:

```
Error: updating Lambda Function (bff-test-alpha-step-fn-l-a680) configuration: operation error Lambda: UpdateFunctionConfiguration, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: df8cb828-2a8a-427f-b00f-f64f7e99e311, InvalidParameterValueException: Layer conversion failed: Could not scan one or more directories;
```

I'm utilizing the following Terraform module:

`registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws`

If I remove the dependencies, it works, but I want to find and understand the root cause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html#troubleshooting-deployment-LayerConversionFailed?